# Reduce, Piecewise function gives result that does not make any sense given condition constraint

Tags: equation-solving, maximum

Here is my code:

```
N1 = 1;
N2 = 1;
 X1 = N2/(1 - \[Sigma]);


   c = 1
surpluspayoff10011010 = (N1 + x + y)/((N1 + x + y) + N2)* X1 - 
   c y - (((N1 + x)/((N1 + x) + N2))*X1);
yargmax10011010 = Simplify[y /. NSolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((surpluspayoff10011010)\)\) ==
        0, y]][[2]];
yargmax10011010 = 
  Simplify[Piecewise[{{0, 
      Simplify@
       Reduce[{Rationalize@yargmax10011010 < 0  && 0 <= \[Sigma] < 1 && 
          ymax > 1}, x]}, {yargmax10011010, 
      Simplify@
       Reduce[{Rationalize@yargmax10011010 <= ymax && 
          0 <= \[Sigma] < 1 && ymax > 1}, x]}, {ymax, 
      Simplify@
       Reduce[{Rationalize@yargmax10011010 > ymax && 
          0 <= \[Sigma] < 1 && ymax > 1}, x]  }}]];
surpluspayoff10011010 = 
  Simplify[(N1 + yargmax10011010 + 
        x)/((N2) + (N1 + x + yargmax10011010))* X1 - 
    yargmax10011010 - (((N1 + x)/((N1 + x) + N2))*X1) ];
yargmax10011010 = 
  Simplify[Piecewise[{{0, 
      Simplify@
       Reduce[{Rationalize@surpluspayoff10011010 < 0 && 
          0 <= \[Sigma] < 1  && ymax > 1}, x]}, {yargmax10011010, 
      Simplify@
       Reduce[{Rationalize@surpluspayoff10011010 >= 0 && 
          0 <= \[Sigma] < 1 && ymax > 1}, x]}}]];
```

I cannot put the result here, since it will look very ugly here. But the thing is I already gave the condition for 0<\sigma<1 , 1< ymax, but the result for yargmax10011010 is something that violated these conditions. Basicly,look at the result of yargmax10011010 when y=0, we have conditions such as ymax =<1, and such

Comment: Your code is complex and somewhat messy. Perhaps you could reduce it to a simpler example. Nevertheless, I suspect that your problem ultimately is that you did not explicitly give appropriate assumptions when using `Simplify`. If  you want to set global assumptions, so you don't have to specify them every time you run `Simplify`, look into [`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html). You may also be interested in this tutorial: [Using assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that

Comment: It did not work, the result still does not make sense (basicly we have for yargmax 2 values that overlap)

Comment: It doesn't appear that any of your 9 `Simplify` or 5 `Rationalize` are accomplishing anything for you. With or without those I get the result `Piecewise[{{0, ymax<=1 || 2+x+Sqrt[1/(1-σ)]!=0 || σ>=1 || σ<0}, 
{(2+x+Sqrt[1-σ]-2*σ-x*σ)/(σ-1), 2+x+Sqrt[1/(1-σ)]>=0 && 2+x+ymax+Sqrt[1/(1-σ)]>=0 && 0<=σ<1] && ymax>1}}, ymax]`

Comment: Hi Bill, please look at my comment in Jack post

Comment: I use Rationalize for my own purpose, which I did not write in the OP, because it is not relevant here (but to add more information, I need to do some proof, so I need explicit form of solution)

Comment: There is one other item I notice, since you say the `Piecewise` domains are the issue. In your first `Piecewise` in your code you have: `Piecewise[{{0,yargmax10011010 < 0 && ...}, {yargmax10011010, 
yargmax10011010 <= ymax && ...}, {ymax, yargmax10011010 > ymax && ...`
Should that second case be `0<=yargmax10011010 <= ymax`? If I make that change then the result from your code is different.

Comment: In response to your comment at the bottom about how the cases of `Piecewise` are not disjoint and make no sense. If you look at the documentation for `Piecewise` and you click on the orange `Details` you should see "The condi are evaluated in turn, until one of them is found to yield True." In other words this is not some foundations of mathematics where every case is defined to be disjoint from every other case, this is just programming where it plods along doing one statement after another until it is done. I could write -3<x<3 for the first and -6<x<6 second. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: "In other words this is not some foundations of mathematics where every case is defined to be disjoint from every other case, this is just programming where it plods along doing one statement after another until it is done. I could write -3<x<3 for the first and -6<x<6 second. Does that make more sense now?", Yes I understand now, thank you for the response. I am new to Mathematica and just want to use it to do some proof using it, which previously I solved by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used simpler variable names (e.g., `y1` in place of `yargmax10011010`) and rather than redefining them created new ones (this last because when you are tracking down a problem it often is better not to redefine variables).

I believe that MarcoB is correct, adding assumptions to `Simplify` removes the offending inequalities.

```
N1 = 1;
N2 = 1;
X1 = N2/(1 - σ);
c = 1;

s1 = (N1 + x + y)/((N1 + x + y) + N2)*X1 - 
  c y - (((N1 + x)/((N1 + x) + N2))*X1)
(* -y - (1 + x)/((2 + x) (1 - σ)) + 
 (1 + x + y)/((2 + x + y) (1 - σ)) *)
```

The first pass

```
y1 = Simplify[y /. NSolve[D[s1, y] == 0, y]][[2]]
(* (2. + x + Sqrt[1. - 1. σ] - 2. σ - 
 1. x σ)/(-1. + σ) *)
```

The second pass

```
y2 = Simplify[
  Piecewise[{
    {0, Simplify@
      Reduce[{Rationalize@y1 < 0 && 0 <= σ < 1 && ymax > 1}, 
       x]}, {y1, 
     Simplify@
      Reduce[{Rationalize@y1 <= ymax && 0 <= σ < 1 && 
         ymax > 1}, x]}, {ymax, 
     Simplify@
      Reduce[{Rationalize@y1 > ymax && 0 <= σ < 1 && ymax > 1},
        x]}}
   ], 
  ymax > 1
  ]
```

I will have to use a snapshot for the result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `y2` for new version of `s1`

```
s2 = Simplify[(N1 + y2 + x)/((N2) + (N1 + x + y2))*X1 - 
      y2 - (((N1 + x)/((N1 + x) + N2))*X1), ymax > 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and finally

```
y3 = Simplify[
  Piecewise[{
    {0, Simplify@
      Reduce[{Rationalize@s2 < 0 && 0 <= \[Sigma] < 1 && ymax > 1}, 
       x]}, {y2, 
     Simplify@
      Reduce[{Rationalize@s2 >= 0 && 0 <= \[Sigma] < 1 && ymax > 1}, 
       x]}
    }],
  ymax > 1
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As you can see, the result makes no sense, just look at it, in the first line  2+x+square root of blah blah is always greater than 0 , and in the second line 2+x+ square root is always larger than 0 as well, so y can be both 0 and the second thing at the same time. So if  0<sigma<1, we have 2 values of y , at the same time

Comment: Your question as I understood it was about violating constraints. In this example the constraints are not violated but are redundant (with `ymax > 1` the second statement is not required). Did you want the redundant  constraint removed?

Comment: The result is wrong, just plug in sigma equal 0.95, ymax equal 2 for example, and you see y is equal to 0. And just think about it, the function is not maximized at y=0. I used Nsolve to find max because the function is concave. But thanks anyways for your help, I think maybe I should solve this on paper, perhaps?

Comment: I am not familiar with the problem and am unable to tell whether zero is  wrong. Setting sigma =0.95 and ymax = 2, when I plot `y1` I get a line. When I plot y2 I get a constant of 2 below -8.47214, a constant of zero above . -6.47214 and a line connecting the two between.those bounds. For 'y3' I get zero everywhere.

Comment: The first condition is true everywhere except `x==6.47214` and produces zero. The second condition is true at  `x==6.47214` and the expression computes to be zero.